# Twitter API - get tweets near gps point

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, twitter

I have been looking around the Twitter api without much luck.

Does anyone know if it provides a way to pass in a gps point and in return get a list of tweets that were made near that point?

I've looked around and haven't been able to find much on the topic, has anyone had any experience with this?

I am hopefully going to use such a call in an MVC3 .net application.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the search API, specifically "geocode". From https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search:

```
Returns tweets by users located within a given radius of the given latitude/longitude. The     location is preferentially taking from the Geotagging API, but will fall back to their Twitter profile. The parameter value is specified by "latitude,longitude,radius", where radius units must be specified as either "mi" (miles) or "km" (kilometers). Note that you cannot use the near operator via the API to geocode arbitrary locations; however you can use this geocode parameter to search near geocodes directly.

Example Values: 37.781157,-122.398720,1mi
```

Comment: Thank you, its something like...http://search.twitter.com/search?q=to%3Atwitter%20until%3A2011-05-07&geocode=37.781157,-122.398720,25mi